# multipart/form-data submit vs text/xml response

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, multipartform-data

I use Python script serve uploading files to a server. The upload form is served by `jQuery.form`

*HTML:*

```
<form id="form_upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="py/uploader.py" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
<input name="uploadedfile" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

At the end of the upload procedure, I want the `uploader.py` to return me some information about the uploaded file. I return this information in xml format and later want to interpret it by jQuery.

*uploader.py:*

```
# ...
# serve the file
return "<info size=\"%s\"></info>" % size
```

The jQuery should then look like that:

*jQuery:*

```
$("#form_upload").submit( function() {
    var options = {
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml_response) { /*xml_response is the xml returned by uploader.py*/
            var size = $(xml_response).find("info").attr("size");
            // display size
            // ...
        }
    }

    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
    return false;
});
```

Now, the problem is that xml_response is not recognized as my xml: instead of the string I produced, I get

`<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;"> here my xml, escaped </pre>`

If the `enctype` in the `form` was `text/xml` , then `success` function recieves right xml object, but then uploading a file is impossible. How to solve that?

Comment: Jakub, what you want to do is return the data only and manipulate the HTML using jQuery. So either generate XML or JSON from your uploader.py.

JSON:
[{
"sizeinfo" : 89283,
"otherinfo" : "12345"
}]